# If in JSON there are two or more identical week number, return the last week_number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

If in JSON there are two or more identical week number, return the last week_number. See the example. Thank you.

Method in controllers.

```
def all
  @weekly_updates = current_user.user_updates.latest.offset(params[:offset] || 0)
end
```

Method in a model that calculates the week number:

```
class UserUpdate < ActiveRecord::Base
  def week_number
    return 1 unless user.first_program_started_at.present?
    (((created_at.utc) - user.first_program_started_at.utc.beginning_of_day) / 86400 / 7).ceil.to_i || 1
  end
end
```

JSON:

```
json.weekly_updates @weekly_updates do |j1,  weekly_update|
  j1.week_number weekly_update.try(:week_number)
end
```

example:

```
"weekly_updates":
[
  {
    "id":25392,
    "created_at":"2014-03-21T10:13:54+04:00",
    "week_number":2
  }
  ,
  {
    "id":25393,
    "created_at":"2014-03-20T23:59:59+04:00",
    "week_number":2
  }
  {
    "id":25394,
    "created_at":"2014-03-26T23:59:59+04:00",
    "week_number":3
  }
]
```

should get this.

```
"weekly_updates":
[
  {
    "id":25393,
    "created_at":"2014-03-20T23:59:59+04:00",
    "week_number":2
  }
  {
    "id":25394,
    "created_at":"2014-03-26T23:59:59+04:00",
    "week_number":3
  }
]
```

Comment: Maybe you should take this to the controller. Since you are using @weekly_updates, I assume there is a declaration of it.

Comment: @StavrosSouvatzis I thought about it. But I was not able to change something. Maybe you have an idea how to do it?

Comment: Can you show us the controller code where @weekly_updates comes from?

Comment: @StavrosSouvatzis `@weekly_updates = current_user.user_updates.latest.offset(params[:offset] || 0)`

Comment: You need an sql solution there. Something like select("distinct week_number, max(id), created_at").group(:week_number), but I don't know exactly how to build it. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just bumped onto this and it worked on my tests:

```
def all
  @weekly_updates = current_user.user_updates.maximum(:id, :group => week_number)
end
```

(but it was with week_number as an actual row)